# Why was `unsigned int` causing the program to crash?

Tags: c++

I had to make a program that checks if two words can be obtained one from the other by permutating the letters. I wrote the code as you can see below and I struggled quite a long time to find out why the program is crashing, and at some point I  had the idea to change the fundametal type of these variables from `unsigned int` (`unsigned int code = 0, i, j, counter = 0, ok = 1;`) to `integer` (`int code = 0, i, j, counter = 0, ok = 1;`) and now it works properly but I don't know what changed so that now it works. I know (please correct me if I'm wrong) that `unsigned int` goes from 0 (including 0) to a very large number. All the variables were not going under 0, so I don't know why it didin't work in the `unsigned int` version and how the fundamental type changing solved the crash.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{   char word1[50], word2[50];
    unsigned int code = 0, i, j, counter = 0, ok = 1;

    cout << "Type in the first word and then press ENTER:";
    cin.getline(word1, 50);
    cout << "Type in the second word and then press ENTER:";
    cin.getline(word2, 50);
    cout << endl;

    if (strlen(word1) == strlen(word2)) //If the two words don't have the same lenght, it's impossible to obtain one word of the other by permutating it's letters.

    {   for (i = 0; word1[i]; i++)  /*This nested FOR will generate a number in the code variable. The first digit will indicate how many times will the letter word1[0] be found in word2,
                                    the second digit will indicate how many times will the letter word1[1] be found in word2 and so on until the end of word1*/
        {   counter = 0;
            for (j = 0; word2[j]; j++)
                if (word1[i] == word2[j])
                    counter += 1;

            code = code * 10 + counter;
        }

        i = strlen(word1) - 1;

        while (i >= 0 && ok)    /*In this loop we are checking if the code is valable also for the word1 itself. If it is, it means that the words can be obtained one of the other by permutating the letters*/
        {   counter = 0;        
            for (j = strlen(word1) - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                if (word1[i] == word1[j])
                    counter++;

            if (counter == code % 10)
                ok = 1;
            else
                ok = 0;

            code = code / 10;
            i--;
        }

        if (ok)
            cout << "Yes, the words can be obtained one of the other by permutating the letters.";
        else
            cout << "No, the words can not be obtained one of the other by permutating the letters.";
    }

    else
        cout << "No, the words can not be obtained one of the other by permutating the letters.";

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Extract a minimal example before posting here, your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginners mistake: Consider that if i is an unsigned int, i >= 0 will always be true. It cannot be false. If you set i to 0 and then subtract 1, you will get a very large positive number.

If your compiler didn't give you a warning, ask someone to show you how to turn more warnings on.

Comment: I'm working in Visual Studio 2015, and yes, I am a beginner.

Comment: The warning should appear when I'm debugging ? I get only a crash error saying something of a stack overflow.

Comment: The warning should appear when you compile your application. Not when you debug.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your code goes:

```
while (i >= 0 && ok) { /* ...stuff here... */  --i; }
```

With an unsigned, if i is 0 and you decrement it, it will become the maximum unsigned value.  As a result, i is always greater than or equal to 0 and the while loop keeps executing.

My guess is that is what is happening, and then, when you access word[i] you are accessing outside of the bounds of the array and crashing.

Comment: So, should I use always `integer` variables as indexes so that the value of the variable can get to `-1` and when the `while` will do the test, it will stop the loop?

Comment: @Skyp89 That's a tough question.  A lot of people recommend you should (almost) always use signed types to avoid these kinds of boundary issues, so that's a legitimate way to program.  Personally, in C++, I often use unsigned types for things that should be unsigned, like array lengths and indices; it just means I have to be careful if I have loops that are going backwards.  One solution is to loop from 0 to <length and then access the array using length-1-index.  Another solution is to loop from length to >0 and then access the array using index-1.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is probably from the following code:

```
for (j = strlen(word1) - 1; j >= 0; j--)
```

because you defined j as unsigned int the for loop goes on for ever and never breaks.

Comment: So, should I use always integer variables as indexes so that the value of the variable can get to -1 and when the while will do the test again, it will stop the loop?

Comment: @Skyp89 when you define condition for your loop you should let your variable to fail the test so your loop breaks (in this case becomes negative) so yes you should define it as int in this case

Comment: Sometimes I do something like this in this situation: `for(j=strlen(word1)-1; j+1; --j)` or `while (i+1 && ok)`   "`x+1`" evaluates to false for both signed and unsigned integer types when `x` has the value you get when zero is decremented by one.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles, can you explain a little bit better how this test (`j+1` or `i+1`) works inside the `for` loop? I can not see how the `for` loop checks this condition at a iteration.

Comment: @Skyp89 Before each iteration of a for loop, the `for` statement's second expression is evaluated.  Looping ends when this evaluates to a false boolean value.  Your original conditional expression is `j >= 0`, which is always "true" for an unsigned integer.  For a signed integer, it is "false" only when `j` has a negative value.  Because an integer value evaluates as "false" when equal to zero (and only when zero), I suggested raplacting the conditional with `j+1`, which is zero (thus "false") when `j` is one below zero `((0-1)+1)==0`.